# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, apache

Estou fazendo meu sistema de login e esta dando o seguinte erro na hora de fazer login:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 41

```
if (isset($_POST['entrar']) && $_POST['entrar'] == "login")
    {
    $usuario = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    if (empty($usuario) || empty($senha))
        {
        echo "Prencha TODOS os campos";
        }
      else
        {
        $query = "SELECT nome, email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $busca = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($busca > 0)
            {
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $linha['nome'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $linha['email'];
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Login ou senha ligado";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Cuidado ao fazer edições no código da pergunta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado, pelo alerta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não utilize a função `mysql`, utilize a `mysqli`.

Não devemos usar funções da extensão "mysql" pelo seu desenvolvimento ter sido descontinuado; a extensão vai *já é obsoleta*, ou seja, código que utilize essas funções não funcionam.

Para maiores detalhes veja: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: **Nota do moderador:** resposta restaurada porque responde sim à pergunta. Pelo erro, o AP está usando uma versão do PHP que já não tem mais as funções `mysql_*`.

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui!

Comment: @Alan007BR Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.